# Schedule an event in 10 minutes after receiving Kafka message

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a Java app which has a Kafka consumer. It is recieves messages, stores them in a db and sends them for execution to another application via Rest API. I want to schedule an event in 10 minutes after each message is received to check on the status of the message and if the message is not processed, it has to be discarded.

What is the best way to implement this? Any library or framework?

Answer (score 0):

there are various method you can use it (cron job):

1) use this example code `new java.util.Timer().schedule` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)):

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code here
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

2) use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`:

```
// When your program starts up
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// then, when you want to schedule a task
Runnable task = ....    
executor.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// and finally, when your program wants to exit
executor.shutdown();
```

it's important to shutdown the executor when you've finished. The `shutdown()` method will cleanly shut down the thread pool when the last task has completed, and will block until this happens. `shutdownNow()` will terminate the thread pool immediately.

3) use of [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/index.php) for cron expessions and scheduling `cronTrigger.getExpressionSummary()` :

```
 CronTrigger t = new CronTrigger();
 t.setCronExpression("0 30 10-13 ? * WED,FRI");
 System.out.println(""+t.getExpressionSummary());
```

4) example of using `javax.swing.Timer` :

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // Code to be executed
  }
});
timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
timer.start(); // Go go go!
```

This code will only be executed once, and the execution happens in 3000 ms (3 seconds).

Comment: Thanks Taher. If I use `Timer`, how scalable and accurate would that be? I might be getting thousands of messages per minute.

Comment: you're welcome, maybe you can use http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ => read this document (quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs)